# Invoking a deleted constructor in C++

Tags: constructor, new-operator, invoke, delete-operator, parameterized

```
class one: public two {
  public: explicit one (specifier const& use_case);
  one() = delete;
  void stat(Statistic val);
};
```

I need to test the above mentioned public interface "void stat(Statistic stat)" using Libfuzzer Library, So i wrote the code as follows:

Result: **Error:** call to deleted constructor **'one'**
Question: Though the constructor is marked as explicitly deleted, how can i invoke or create a constructor and successfully execute the code snippet below?

```
extern "C" LLVM..(Data, Size) {
  Statistics val = Size; //Assigning the size;
  one obj; //Creating an instance of one
  obj.stat(val); //Call stat function and pass the value return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Tried with this code snippet and was expecting to successfully pass the value

Answer (score 0):

"Reinvoke" is a weird word, it doesn't make sense in C++.

You create a constructor by changing `one() = delete;` to `one() { /* function body */ }`.

This cannot be done outside the class, or after compilation. It may be easier to create a `one` object by passing a `specifier` value.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you could post an example (code snippet) to test obj.stat(val);. I can understand it better, since I am new to this C++

Comment: @SNH: No idea, you didn't provide the definition of `specifier`.